# Can't load google map Geojson data in IE 9

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9, geojson

I'm getting the below error when trying to load GeoJson data in a map in IE9 using Javascript

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

My method call looks like below

```
myMap.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
```

I believe it has something to do with the .data call, as the only lines it happens on are ones that include .data in them. The "myMap" variable is initialized and set to a google map, and that all works fine, it's just when I try to load the geojson that it breaks.

Does anyone know why it would be breaking in IE9?

I've also attached a shot from Browserstack on similar errors using the google demo page...

[image: IE9 Geojson Bug]

UPDATE: I've talked to a google developer directly and it seems like a bug currently with IE9 (and I believe 8 as well), loading geojson does not work. If anyone does find a workaround though, it would be greatly appreciated. Even just knowing exactly why it's breaking would be good...

Comment: Have you tried on other browsers? What is the result on other browsers?

Comment: see if [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810368/mapbox-markers-from-geojson-not-appearing-in-ie9) is relevant

Comment: Does this example work for you? https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/layer-data-simple

Comment: Just tried that example on my IE 9 VM and it didn't work, also tested on browser stack, does it work for anyone else that has IE 9 ?

Comment: @larryp It works on all other browsers except IE 8 and 9, works on 10, and works on Chrome and all of those.

Comment: @larryp Also that link you sent me doesn't apply to me since I'm using googles API and not Leaflets. Doesn't seem like it will do me any good...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with IE.

Try this:

Open IE, Open "Tools", click on "Compatibility View Settings" and then uncheck "disable intranet sites in Compatibility View Setting" and then try to open your page.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code loads the GeoJSON from a different server (cross-domain).

The problem is that .loadGeoJson() is using XMLHttpRequest to load the data, and on IE8 and IE9 this doesn't work cross-domain.

This is the "Access is denied" error you can see in the console.

Try putting the GeoJSON on the same server.

Or, if you really need to load GeoJSON cross-domain and support IE9, use an ajax library, and the .addGeoJson() method. It would look something like this using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(geojson) {
        myMap.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
    }
    // Other options to configure for jsonp, etc.
});
```